# URLConnection throws a FileNotFoundException. How do I discover this was caused by a 404?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I've got this code:

```
String buildUrl = DEFAULT_HOST + "/job/" + jobName + "/" + buildNumber + API_PATH;
URLConnection connection = new URL(buildUrl).openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

If that `buildUrl` results in a 404 response, that last line throws a `FileNotFoundException`.  But, I want to know that the server returned a 404 because I don't trust that `FileNotFoundException` *always means* 404 and I want to do something special when 404s occur.

How do I know when a 404 occurs when using a `URLConnection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, cast to `HttpURLConnection` then call `connection.connect()` instead of `getInputStream`. Once done, call `getResponceCode()`. If all is good, then you can get the input stream

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a 3rd party library then look at apache commons http client component project. This library has much more user friendly http api than native url connection api  in jdk.

Comment: When I need low level features, I use it.  But I disagree with what you're saying.  I think HttpClient's api is pretty annoying to use.

Comment: I am suggesting newer httpcomponents library. Not the older httpclient 3.0 lib.

Comment: That's the one I'm talking about.  In fact, I think the older one has a better api.